# Problemas utilizando la libreria v-money con VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente al utilizar la librería **`v-money`** sucede que al momento de realizar los pasos correctamente para utilizar la librería en base a su documentación https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-money al agregar datos al campo money, se transforma de manera inesperada, tomando 3 dígitos como decimales.

Esta muestra es la manera correcta que se debe mostrar los datos en el campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de hacer click en otro lado de la pantalla automáticamente el campo se transforma con 3 decimales a la derecha, cuando en la propiedades de money solo coloque que se acepte 2 decimales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//CURRENCY
      money: {
        decimal: ".",
        thousands: ".",
        prefix: "",
        suffix: "",
        precision: 2,
        masked: false /* doesn't work with directive */
      }
```

Adjunto los siguientes fragmentos de código.

Este código es el campo money:

```
<v-text-field
    v-if="showTextFields"
    v-model.lazy="impactCost"
    v-money="money"
    :counter="10"
    maxlength="10"
    label="Impacto en Costo"
    color="secondary"
    :disabled="$store.state.project.rolProject == 'Coordinador' ? false : true"
    @blur="editImpactCost()"
    @keyup="isToEdit = false"
    >
    <template v-slot:prepend>
        <v-icon size="20">fa-dollar-sign</v-icon>
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Código donde se declara la variable impactCost:

```
computed: {
    impactCost: {
      set(impactCost) {
        this.$store.commit("SET_IMPACT_COST", impactCost);
      },
      get() {
        return this.issue.impact_cost;
      }
    },
}
```

Código del metodo editImpactCost:

```
async editImpactCost() {
      const id_issue = this.issue.id;
      const impactCost = this.issue.impactCost;
      await axios.post(Url_base + "/issue/editar/impact_cost", {
        id_issue: id_issue,
        impact_cost: impactCost
      });
    },
```

En la tabla esta de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

una saludo, algo tarde la respuesta, sin embargo a alguien mas le puede servir, básicamente el problema es que usas para separador de miles y para separador decimal el punto (.), esto genera conflicto en el componente, prueba con hacer (.) para miles y (,) para decimales, o viceversa según su conveniencia.

Comment: Hola @user211986. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»